# Implicit conversion of Traversable contents in Scala

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion

I am trying to create an implicit converter that would would use a implicit converter that's currently in scope `(eg. A => B)` and would be able to convert any type of `Traversable[A]` to `Traversable[B]`.

So far I got:

```
implicit def convertLists[A, B](from: Traversable[A])(implicit conv: A => B): Traversable[B] = from.map(conv)
```

This however does not work with:

```
val listOfB: List[B] = convertLists(List[A]())
```

If I change `Traversable` to `List`, then it works fine, eg:

```
implicit def convertLists[A, B](from: List[A])(implicit conv: A => B): List[B] = from.map(conv)
```

Do I need to add anything else to allow the converter to accept any subclass of `Traversable`?

Comment: If you define the implicit conversion properly, it works as expected. What error are you seeing.

Comment: I think the problem is that your method returns a `Traversable[B]` but the type parameter of `listOfB` is `List[B]`.

Comment: @EndeNeu but `List` is a subclass of `Traversable`

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov It just doesn't pick up the converter and results in type mismatch.

Comment: Is your converter in scope? Could it be that there is another conversion interfering with your implicit conversion?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov it is in scope. As I mentioned, if I change `Traversable` to `List`, then it works - without any other changes.

Comment: @ArtursVancans `List` is a subclass of `Traversable` but not the other way around. As @ende-neu noted, your method returns `Traversable[B]` and then you try to assign it to variable with type `List[B]`.

Comment: The standard library has all kinds of magic (in the form of `canConverteTo` implicits) in order to maintain the source type of a collection for instance, when you do `.map` (say, if I give you a list, I want to receive a list). Check them out, you might be able to reuse them.

Comment: @sainaen right. so it's covariance and invariance stuff. makes sense.

Comment: @ArtursVancans not exactly. It's just a standard type incompatibility -- your method returns something that isn't assignable to variable of declared type. But it is possible to implement what you want with some amount of implicit magic, just follow an example of `map` or `filter` from the `TraversableLike` as @Daniel L. suggested.

Comment: ...or, you know, you can try the simple stuff: `val listOfB: List[B] = convertLists(List[A]()).toList` or `to*` if you need other conversions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have explicitly defined `convertLists` to return `Traversable[B]`. `Traversable` is not a subtype of `List` (it's its supertype), so the result of `convertLists` (`Traversable`) can't be a return type of `listOfB` (`List`).

You can define `convertLists` to infer the result type based on the type of its argument, if you use `CanBuildFrom`:

```
import scala.collection.TraversableLike
import scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom
import scala.language.higherKinds

// `CC` is some concrete subtype of `Traversable`
// `That` is an automatically inferred result collection type
implicit def convertLists[A, B, CC[T] <: TraversableLike[T, CC[T]], That](
  from: CC[A]
)(
  implicit
    conv: A => B,
    // witness that it's possible to build 
    // a collection with elements `B` from a collection `CC[A]`, 
    // and compute the resulting collection type `That`
    bf: CanBuildFrom[CC[A], B, That]
): That = from.map(conv)
```

Now assuming the following simple definition of `A` and `B`

```
case class A(i: Int)
case class B(i: Int)
implicit def aisb(a: A): B = B(a.i)
```

The following works:

```
val listOfB: List[B] = convertLists(List[A](A(1)))
```

And you don't have to call `convertLists` explicitly:

```
val listOfB2: List[B] = List[A](A(1))
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the approach in scala collections library you could come out with such code:

```
import scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom
import scala.collection.TraversableLike

implicit val boolToInt = (b: Boolean) => if (b) 1 else 0
implicit def convertLists[A, B, Repr, That](from: TraversableLike[A, Repr])(implicit conv: A => B, bf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, B, That]): That = from map conv
val listOfB: List[Int] = List(true, false)
```

which gives

```
listOfB: List[Int] = List(1, 0)
```